# Comparisons of ECDSA, EdDSA and BLS Signatures in Blockchain: Pros and Cons

Tags: signature, dsa, cryptocurrency, ed25519, bls-signature

As we know, the most used digital scheme in Blockchain is ECDSA. For now, more and more blockchain projects, I've noticed, are considering substituting EdDSA and BLS signature scheme as the new one. Could anyone offer a bird-view about their respective pros and cons if applied in the Blockchain industry?

Comment: "Blockchain" isn't such special an industry to merit its own treatment of digital signature algorithms. ECDSA is the most supported elliptic curve signature algorithm, EdDSA is more easily implemented correctly, and BLS is the most compact. That's it.

Comment: Well, the block chains do like smaller signatures for sure. Or any other method to save space, or the block chain grows too much.

Answer (score 1):

EdDSA and BLS are well known to support aggregation techniques (aggregation of public keys or signatures). This property makes them well-demanded in applications where you have many different signatures from different users and want to verify them all in one shot, rather than one by one. Unfortunately, ECDSA does not support aggregation for more than two users.